# Change contact form captions from joomla

Tags: joomla, title, joomla3.0, contact-form, caption

I am beginner to joomla, I tried very hard but could not fix it. These titles on Contact form. I tried to change text but I could not found How can I find it?

[image]

Comment: Which contact form? The built-in Joomla component or a 3rd party extension? Either one, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use the language override feature, which you will find in the language manager.

Answer (score 0):

Log into your Joomla 3.0 Admin Dashboard

In the top menu, click Extensions and then click Language Manager

In the left menu, click Overrides

In the top left of the page, click New

Find the Constant or Value to change

creating-a-new-language-overrideUnder Search text you want to change and next to Search for choose Value. Then, type in the text you want to change (Written by in our example) and click Search.

Under Search Results, click on the only result. This will automatically fill in the details for you under Create a New Override.

Change the Text

Under Create a new Override and next to Text, you'll see the Value. Change this to the text your prefer.